# Add index to generated column

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, denormalization

First, sorry if the used terms are not right. I'm not a mySQL-professional.

I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `accesses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accessed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_accesses_on_accessed_at` (`accessed_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9278483 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This table has **10.000.000** rows in it. I use it to generate charts, with queries like this :

```
SELECT SUM(time) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS date
FROM `accesses`
GROUP BY date;
```

This query is very long (more than 1 minute). I'm doing lots of others queries (with `AVG`, `MIN` or `MAX` instead of `SUM`, or with a `WHERE` on a specific day or month, or `GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)`, etc...)

I want to optimize it.
The best idea I have is to add several columns, with redundancy, like `DATE(created_at)`, `HOUR(created_at)`, `MONTH(created_at)`, then add an index on it.

... Is this solution good or is there any other one ?

Regards

Comment: It may be wise to give the full table declaration, output of: `SHOW CREATE TABLE accesses`

Comment: 1 minute is hella long for a simple select query like that, even with the amount of records that you have. I'd take this question to [DatabaseAdministrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: well, he does `group` and `sum` on 10 mil records, without restricting the result set...

Comment: @NDM > I edited my post. I do no restriction because I know my result is never > than 60 records.

Comment: You misunderstood. You are going through entire 10 million rows, and the result is 60 rows due to grouping. Your query has no restriction. That means that you're either CPU or I/O bound (most likely both) which is due to hardware. The question here is not about indexes, they can't help reduce the data set in question. You have to go through all of it. What you can do is cache results or ensure you can stick entire dataset in RAM so that traversal will be quick. Certain operations can be optimized only up until a certain level where you are hardware-bound.

Comment: @Strawberry :D f***ing copy paste

Comment: adding new columns and indexes might make searching slightly faster, but it makes insert and delete operations slower.  Its a balancing act (if it worked any other way, everyone would have every column indexed).  Also, grouping by datetime can be very slow.  I'm not sure by your question what you exactly want out of this table, but indexing a bunch of stuff is not a speed solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be an optimization to store data redundantly in permanent columns with an index to optimize certain queries. This is one example of *denormalization*.

Depending on the amount of data and the frequency of queries, this can be an important speedup (@Marshall Tigerus downplays it too much, IMHO).

I tested this out by running EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> explain SELECT SUM(time) AS value, DATE(created_at) AS date FROM `accesses` GROUP BY date\G                      *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: accesses
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Ignore the fact that the table is empty in my test. The important part is `Using temporary; Using filesort` which are expensive operations, especially if your temp table gets so large that MySQL can't fit it in memory.

I added some columns and indexes on them:

```
mysql> alter table accesses add column cdate date, add key (cdate), 
  add column chour tinyint, add key (chour), 
  add column cmonth tinyint, add key (cmonth);

mysql> explain SELECT SUM(time) AS value, cdate FROM `accesses` GROUP BY cdate\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: accesses
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: cdate
          key: cdate
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
```

The temporary table and filesort went away, because MySQL knows it can do an index scan to process the rows in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. My query is done in less thant 400 ms. Nice !

Comment: Glad to help! Now you have to write triggers on insert and update to keep those generated columns in sync with the created_date.